# summarize silverlight multithreading access rules

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight

Can someone be so kind as to give me a concise (general is fine) set of rules for what data/methods can and cannot be accessed from a secondary (non-UI) thread?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it is any DependencyObject that was created by the UIThread.

I would suggest using this extension method, when you are not sure...

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void FastInvoke(this Dispatcher dispatcher, Action action)
    {
        if (dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            action.Invoke();
        else
            dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Dispatcher.FastInvoke(delegate
                {
                    StatusMessageText.Text = "OK";
                });
```

Comment: thanks- that's a good start.  I can also tell that if a UI element is bound to a property of an INotifyPropertyChanged derived object, then modifying this property's value in a background thread will also fail. 
So it would seem any UI element or property which is bound to a UI element will cause an error if accessed by a non-UI thread.
 Are there any other rules?